# How to install Wxpython with Anaconda (windows)?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, wxpython

I've been using Anaconda for Python and I am having a problem finding a comprehensive guide on how to install Wxpython.

From what I've pieced together, I downloaded Wxpython from condaforge then entered 'conda install -c anaconda wxpython' into the Anaconda prompt.

and then when i went to Spyder and typed in 'import wx' nothing happens. How do I get Wxpython up and running?

Comment: you need to check if you are in the right enviornment, where do you open your spyder, is it the root enviornment?

Comment: in spyder if you run it, and no error comes, the import was sucessfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first step I would check if you are loading spyder in the root enviorment:
[image]

if you have naother enviorment, you need to run:
`activate YourEnviorment`
before running

`conda install -c anaconda wxpython`

after this if you run a package in spyder your console will ouput this:

[image]

so in general, if no error occurs, you succesfully loaded your library!